# Having issue while reading '≤' and '≥' signs from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I am having an issue in reading less than equal to (≤) and greater than equal to (≥) from a text files in python.

Python version: 3.8

opening file:

```
read_file = open(input_file,'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
lines = list(read_file.readlines())
```

I have also used encoding 'utf-8' but it shows an error as the file contains some special characters that utf-8 cant interpret.

Actually, signs are read successfully but it is interpreted as '¡Ã' and '¡Â' also sometimes after modifying the file and also in the debugger it gets interpreted something like 'ï¿½ï¿½' which is real trouble.

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to do with these strings? Where the problem actually happens?

Comment: Maybe a case of mixed character sets, or [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: In normal run i am able differentiate both signs with '¡Ã' and '¡Â'

 `match = re.search(r'.*([¡Ã|¡Â|<|>]).*',data_value)
 if match:
  data_value = float(re.sub(r'[¡Ã|¡Â|<|>]','',data_value))`
  
later in the code 

`width = round(data_value,2)`

here, It is making trouble as data_value is not converted to float

Comment: @BhoopeshDewangan did you try "ignore" argument on decode property? you can cancel out all non-utf8 characters (or other encodings) like this: `print(open("input_file", 'rb').read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')) `

Comment: If I use 'ignore' it will ignore '≤' and '≥' signs which I don't want

Comment: Characters `'≤'` and `'≥'` are not defined in `ISO-8859-1`. Try `encoding='cp1252'`.

Comment: @JosefZ not in `cp1252` either.  Perhaps OP can try `locale.getpreferredencoding()` and report back what it says.

Comment: @MarkRansom you are right, My fault…